# How require() searching orders

Tags: javascript, node.js

If a project like:

```
.
├── SubDir
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── module_x
│   └── package.json
├── node_modules
│   └── module_x
└── package.json
```

In app.js, has `var x = require('module_x');`
which module_x will be used?

More general question, how requireJS find modules (The order of search modules)?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS doesn't search the tree looking for modules... you must specify a path and that path doesn't have to match the actual directory layout thanks to the RequireJS configuration settings.

That said, based upon the directory structure you posted, it looks like you are actually asking how Node searches for modules.  Though Node's `require` syntax is similar, it is a very different tool.